# Form submit by click on a div element without JS

Tags: html, css

Let me have a `div` element which is located inside a form as follows:

```
<from id = "someForm">
    <div id = "someDiv">
        <!-- Some Content -->
    </div>
</form>
```

Is there a way to submit the `form#someForm` by clicking on the `div#someDiv` without using `JS`? I can use `CSS3`.

Comment: You want that when the whole div is clicked, the form will be submitted?

Comment: @J.Lucky Yes, I do. I want the enclosing form will submit when I click to the div element block-container.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv : any special reason why you want to go against native methods?

Comment: @NoobEditor Yes, there is. I don't want that the form-submit button is rendered at all.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv : if you don't want html *rendered*, you *will have* to use jQuery or JS...

Comment: @NoobEditor But I cannot use jQuery or JS. Is there a way to clear styles of the submit button as said in the J.Lucky's answer?

Comment: Wouldn't it be wiser to use an `<a>` tag and style that? It will act as a link but just give it an onclick action, you have to declare it will not become a link though.

Comment: Its more or less logic to look for an alternative if you are currently stuck. Although the answer given down there by @NoobEditor is much better than my solution, since buttons are available to be styled to a non looking button. `<a>` tags can be done the same, but require a bit of fiddling in order to do what you want. Anyway, glad to be of help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend doing this but you can wrap a submit button on the `div`.

```
<from id = "someForm">
    <button type="submit">
        <div id = "someDiv">
            <!-- Some Content -->
        </div>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: But in the case the enclosing button is rendered. I need the rendered markup will be the same as we don't add the submit button at all.

Comment: Could you provide such css styles?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv What about using a CSS reset?

Comment: FYI. It's not valid to have a `<div>` within a `<button>` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: I made it clear that I **don't** recommend doing it but he *can* do it. Not because he *can* that doesn't mean it's valid.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to play with `button`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/67wjdv89/)

```
button {
    border:0;
    background:none;
}
```

---

But i would suggest it this way (inline- JS)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/67wjdv89/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="something" onclick="javascript:somefunction();"  >i am here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    border:0;
    background:none;
    cursor :pointer;
    width:100px;
    height:100px
}
```

---

using anchor tag `a` for same

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/67wjdv89/4/)

**HTML**

```
<a id="something" href="javascript:somefun()" <!-- or some url page -->>i am here</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    display:block;
    border:0;
    background:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black
}
```

Comment: As I stated in the comments, the `<a>` tag is his best bet in this case, I think. Glad you put an example down for him.

Comment: Not knocking it but the OP did stipulate "*without* using JS."

Comment: @Dorvalla : yeah....`a` are good to tag *without* `JS`, `div` can do the same *with* `JS`

Comment: @Moob : Glad you asked, except `button` when `a` or `div` is *clicked*, how do you plan to pass on the `form` data to the target page/function?? `;)` ...you'll need JS at the end of the day to parse data if you are not taking `submit` type for consideration...do i make sense!!??

Comment: @NoobEditor That's my point. Without JS an `a` can only be a link - it wont *submit* the form. In that regard, this answer does not meet the requirements to ***submit** the form without JS*.

Comment: @Moob : the `inline-JS` is the only way for that...thats why i laid empahises on `div` method....`javascript:somefunction();` will extract the data on click..thats the idea! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor - But that's JS and is not allowed! The `button` solution alone meets the OP's requirements. Just sayin' ;)

Comment: @Moob : haha...from Noob to Moob..yup..i agree..no arguments with you sir..i just answered what i had in my head, OP can pick if any of it suits him/her! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have an invisible button that entirely covers your content:

```
<form id="someForm">
    <div id="someDiv">
        Some Content
        <input type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
#someDiv {position:relative;}
#someDiv > input {display:block; position:absolute; border:none; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0; opacity:0.01;}
```

EG: http://jsfiddle.net/3q94jq3a/

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell: **No**, you cannot submit a form using only CSS. You must use Javascript to call a function.