# How to submit a value by clicking on a div?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm working on  Asp.net Mvc news website like (yahoo, BBC ...).
I have loads of divs that contains the feed title,text and image.What I want to achieve is to make these divs that contains these 3 elements clickable no matter where I clicked (title,text or feed image)and to post the value of the feed ID to my controller method.
I've done this already like this:

In my feed table I have : FeedID-FeedText-FeedPath

View:

```
  @foreach (Feeds item in Model.FeedViewModel)
  {
  <div class="col-4">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("goToFeed", "Home"))
         {
   <h3>@item.title</h3>>
   <button type ="submit" name="FeedID" value="@item.FeedID" 
   style="background:none; border:none" href="#">@item.FeedText</button>
   <img src="@Url.Content(@item.FeedPath)">
         }
  </div>     
   }
```

And in my controller I'm taking the "FeedID"

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult goToFeed(int FeedID)
    {
     //some code here
    }
```

I guess there should be a way to post the FeedID inside this div without making it a button.

I've checked these posts already but none of them helped me.

[Form submit by click on a div element without JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566809/form-submit-by-click-on-a-div-element-without-js)

[submiting form on div click with js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403112/submiting-form-on-div-click-with-js)

Thanks for any help...

Comment: yeah you could set some JS to handle a click on the div, which would then locate the matching form and run the "submit" method on that form. But...since you don't have any actual form fields inside your form, no values will be sent to the server when you submit. You need some actual fields e.g. hidden fields, textboxes, checkboxes etc as appropriate, so that there's some data for your form to submit. If you just want to submit feed ID then a single hidden field will do the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a POST request to read data. The correct HTTP verb in this case would be GET. POST should mainly be used to create new entries. See [Using HTTP Methods for RESTful Services](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html).

This has not only academic reasons. If you use POST, and your users use the backwards/forwards buttons of the browser to navigate, they would see "Are you sure you want to resubmit the form?" messages.

To use GET, your CSHTML could look like this. Use CSS marker classes `js-feed` and `js-feedId` so you can later access these elements using jQuery.

```
@foreach (Feeds item in Model.FeedViewModel) {
    <div class="col-4 js-feed">
        <h3>@item.title</h3>>
        <span>@item.FeedText</span>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.FeedID, new { @class = "js-feedId" })
    </div>     
}
```

The URL to the GET action is configured in the JS part. Extract the `FeedId` from the clicked `div`, replace the placeholder in the configured URL with this `FeedId`, and then redirect to this action by setting `window.location.href`, which will reload the page.

If you do not want to reload the entire page, use `$.ajax` instead.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var getUrl = '@Url.Action("goToFeed", "Home", new { FeedID = "To_Be_Replaced_By_JS" })';

        $('.js-feed').on('click', function() {
            var feedId = $('.js-feedId', $(this)).val(); // search only inside clicked element
            var feedUrl = getUrl.replace('To_Be_Replaced_By_JS', feedId);
            window.location.href = feedUrl;
        });
     });
</script>
```

The target controller action should be attributed with `[HttpGet]`.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult goToFeed(int FeedID) {
 //some code here
}
```

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
@foreach (Feeds item in Model.FeedViewModel)
{
  <div class="col-4">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("goToFeed", "Home"))
  {
      <h3>@item.title</h3>>
      <button type ="submit" name="FeedID" value="@item.FeedID" 
          style="background:none; border:none" href="#">@item.FeedText</button>
      <img src="@Url.Content(@item.FeedPath)">
  }
  </div>     
}
```

To this:

```
@foreach (Feeds item in Model.FeedViewModel)
{        
    <div class="feed col-4">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("goToFeed", "Home"))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.FeedID)
        <h3>@item.title</h3>>
        <button type ="submit" name="FeedID" value="@item.FeedID" 
            style="background:none; border:none" href="#">@item.FeedText</button>
        <img src="@Url.Content(@item.FeedPath)">
    }
    </div>     
}
```

Then add this to your page:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() { 
    $('.feed').click(function() { 
         return $(this).closest("form").submit();
     });
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: I think you missed some brackets after "submit": `return $(this).closest("form").submit();`

Comment: Thanks for replying, I did exactly what you said and I added the brackets after submit,but the div is not clickable.

Comment: Did you add the `feed` CSS marker class to the `div`?

Comment: There was some syntax error in the js, i fixed it --><script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.feed').click(function() {

            return $(this).closest("form").submit();
        })});
     
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Having a field is required when posting a razor form to the server so having the FieldID hidden will allow this to be sent. Having a div surrounding the area adding the onclick attribute with a submit function to post the above form document.forms[0].submit() can also be used.

```
@foreach (Feeds item in Model.FeedViewModel)
  {
  <div class="col-4">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("goToFeed", "Home"))
         {
          <div onclick="this.parentNode.submit()">
             @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.FeedID)
            <h3>@item.title</h3>>
            <button type ="submit" name="FeedID" value="@item.FeedID" 
               style="background:none; border:none" href="#">@item.FeedText</button>
             <img src="@Url.Content(@item.FeedPath)">
           </div>
         }
   </div> 
   }
```